# Use address as a JSON key value in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a JSON file where the string 'address' is used as a key value.
I used ConvertFrom-Json to get the JSON into powershell.
When I try to use the 'address' key value i get the following output:

```
System.Object&, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e Address(int )
```

When I use precisely the same code for other objects out of the JSON File it works, therefore the question I'm asking is how I can solve the problem with the 'address' object.

The Code I used to convert to JSON.
It is a really large file, therefore in the testing phase I'm reading the JSON into $json one line at a time.

```
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8    
$i = 0
$ig = 0
$output = @()


$Importfile = "Path\file.jsonl"
$Exportfile = "Path\file.csv"
#If file exists, it will be removed

if (test-path $Exportfile) {
    Remove-Item -path $Exportfile
}


foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($Importfile, $encoding)) {
    $json = $line | ConvertFrom-Json
    $index = 1    

    foreach ($item in $json.history.addresses) {

    $CSVLine = "" | Select-Object Addressstreet, Addresspostalcode, Addresscity, Addressstate, Addresscountry, Addresslat, Addresslng, AddressformattedValue, Datum

    $CSVLine.Addressstreet = $json.history.addresses.address.street | Select-Object -First $index | Select-Object -Last 1
    $CSVLine.Addresspostalcode = $json.history.addresses.address.postalcode | Select-Object -First $index | Select-Object -Last 1
    $CSVLine.Addresscity = $json.history.addresses.address.city | Select-Object -First $index | Select-Object -Last 1
    $CSVLine.Addressstate = $json.history.addresses.address.state | Select-Object -First $index | Select-Object -Last 1
    $CSVLine.Addresscountry = $json.history.addresses.address.country | Select-Object -First $index | Select-Object -Last 1
    $CSVLine.Addresslat = $json.history.addresses.address.lat | Select-Object -First $index | Select-Object -Last 1
    $CSVLine.Addresslng = $json.history.addresses.address.lng | Select-Object -First $index | Select-Object -Last 1
    $CSVLine.AddressformattedValue = $json.history.addresses.address.formattedValue | Select-Object -First $index | Select-Object -Last 1
    $CSVLine.Datum =$json.history.addresses.date | Select-Object -First $index | Select-Object -Last 1


    $output += $CSVLine
    $index++
    }

    $i++
    $ig++
    if ($i -ge 20) {
        $output | Export-Csv -Path $Exportfile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
        $i = 0
        $output = @()
        Write-Output $ig 
    }
    if ($ig -ge 120){
        break
    }
}
$output | Export-Csv -Path $Exportfile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -Append
Write-Output $ig
```

The JSON structure:

```
{"history": {
    "names": [{
        "name": {
            "name": "",
            "legalForm": "GmbH"
        },
        "date": "2007-09-18"
    }],
    "addresses": [{
        "address": {
            "street": "",
            "postalCode": ""
        },
        "date": "2019-08-05"
    }]}}
```

Does anyone know how I can get this solved without changing the 'address' key-value in the JSON File?

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but it seems like you are reading one line at a time and updating json variable each time. `$json` is a single line each time and invalid json as well... so, not sure how its supposed to work. Read in all lines first, then convert to json and then access object

Comment: Please provide **valid** json. Test first at [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) or similar.

Comment: You're right, I corrected the JSON and explained more why I'm reading one line at a time. The problem I need to solve is the problem with the 'address' key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `select-object` cmdlet if you're going to reference items in a JSON array

Assuming your JSON is well formed (your included isn't) and you have a JSON entry per line in the file:

```
Get-Content $Importfile -Encoding $encoding | % {
  $json = $_ | ConvertFrom-Json;
  $json | % { $_.history.addresses } | select -expand address
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't get the select object to work with how I build up my current powershell script. I uploaded my entire script now.

Comment: woah! why aren't you using `$item` in your foreach? That has your address info, none of that convoluted $index and select stuff necessary. You want something like `$CSVLine = [pscustomobject]@{ Addressstreet = $item.address.street; Addresspostalcode = $item.address.postalcode }; $output += $CSVLine;`. To get the columns in the right order at the end do ` $output | Select-Object Addressstreet, Addresspostalcode, ...etc..., Datum | Export-Csv ...`

Comment: That's genius!! It solved the problem with the 'address' key and it let the script run 4 times as fast.